# Order by in a update query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
UPDATE table1 
SET date1 = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(date1,'%m/%d/%Y'),INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y'), 
date2 = date2 + 1*24*60*60 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date1,'%m/%d/%Y') DESC;
```

I am trying to `update` all dates in table1 1 day a head (using `MySql`), I am using the query above.
in table1, ad_id + date1 represent a uniqe key and thats why I am using the Order By line.

this query worked on my local data base but when I run it on anther data base I get this  error:

> Duplicate entry '40001305194-07/02/2018' for key 'ad_id_2'

this doesn't make sense since in the data base their is no date 07/02/2018 for this ad_id.
and for date 07/01/2018 there is only 1 line for this ad_id.

what am I doing wrong, thanks in advance :)

Comment: The error means that u can not make second row with information for this key "ad_id_2", so make sure it's not a unique or you don't have unique index

Comment: Since the issue is with the data, not really with the script, you need to add a sample of records on which the above query produces the error described in the question. Without this, I can only support what @tyrlaka wrote.

Comment: there is no ad_id_2 in this table.

I think when it runs the query it creates 2 tables... I am not sure exactly how it runs.

Comment: There must be a column "ad_id_2" where "40001305194-07/02/2018" is already present, and that column is uniquely indexed